# can you trace the number of a phone that used an app to send a text

Tags: mobile

hi within the last few weeks me and 2 other ex work colleagues had texts that was sent though an app called ImNotMe, is there anyway to trace the number who sent the texts

Comment: I'm not sure whether this needs specific understanding of ImNotMe, or a a more general speculation of what's involved in sending texts through apps. In the second case, it may be too broad for SSE. Even in the first case, it is most likely a legal assistance matter with the cooperation of the Service Provider (recovery of information from SP's logs).

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the [ImNot.Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gilapps.imnotme) service is to send anonymous messages. From a technical point of view, the messages are sent by ImNot.Me. The original author of the message is only known to them. That means you need their cooperation to deanonymize the sender.

But they will likely not help you, because it would just be work for them for which they get nothing in return except weaken the privacy guarantee they advertise with (even though their [privacy policy](https://storage.googleapis.com/printy-1384.appspot.com/privacypolicy.htm) only mentions their website, which is quite unprofessional for a service which is based on privacy).

But they might be more cooperative if law enforcement comes around with a subpoena. So when the messages contain anything which warrants to press criminal charges (they are harassing, threatening, insulting or otherwise illegal), you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, any anonimizing or encryption software is useless if your device is already compromised. If it runs Android or Windows, it is probable that it was compromised before you bogught it, iOS is not sure, also depends on the details.

Im not familiar with the service, but if they are not opensource, audited and tested, they can be dataminers who offer "anonimity". Even if they are transparent, they are forced to cooperate with local authorities.

And I was not even mentioning less legal methods.